# ¿como agregar un mensaje en un jTextArea sin que se borre los mensajes anteriores?

Tags: java, socket

amigos, el problema que tengo es que cada vez que envió un mensaje se borra lo que esta en jtextarea y se agrega el mensaje que ha salido del jtxtfield .
lo que necesito es que se acumulen todos los mensajes en el jtexArea porque es una aplicación de chat y se necesita ver la conversación entre los usuarios.
Estaré agradecido por su ayuda...

```
public void enviarMensajes() {
        try {
            try (Socket misocket = new Socket("192.168.250.211", 9000)) {
                paqueteEnvio datos = new paqueteEnvio();
                if (listaCordinadorAs.getSelectedValue().equals("TODOS")) {
                    datos.setCamp("0");
                } else {

                    datos.setCamp(String.valueOf(getIDCamp(listaCordinadorAs.getSelectedValue())));
                }
                datos.setMensaje(txtEscribeAsesor.getText());
                txaConversacionAsesor.setText(datos.getMensaje());
                datos.setNombre(nombre);
                datos.setIp("0");
                ObjectOutputStream paqueteDatos = new ObjectOutputStream(misocket.getOutputStream());
                paqueteDatos.writeObject(datos);
                txtEscribeAsesor.setText("");
                misocket.close();
            }
            txtEscribeAsesor.setText("");

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        //sendNotifi();
    }
```

Aquí lo que se puede ver en el run()

```
while (true) {
                cliente = servidor_cliente.accept();
                ObjectInputStream flujoEntrada = new ObjectInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());
                paqueteRecibido = (paqueteEnvio) flujoEntrada.readObject();
                if (paqueteRecibido.getCamp().equals(String.valueOf(camp)) || paqueteRecibido.getCamp().equals("0")) {
                    //txaConversacionAsesor.setText(paqueteRecibido.getMensaje());
                    sendNotifi(paqueteRecibido.getMensaje());

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que el método `setText()` cambia todo el texto por el `String` que le pasas por parametro, es por ello que solo se muestra el último mensaje. Para lograr agregar el nuevo mensaje sin que se borren los demás debes hacer uso del método `append()`.

Sería cambiar esta línea:

```
txaConversacionAsesor.setText(datos.getMensaje());
```

Por esta otra

```
txaConversacionAsesor.append(datos.getMensaje());
```

Comment: muchas gracias perfecta corrección...